# extract predictors from formulas

Tags: r, formula, lm

Suppose that we have a linear model fitted by

```
lm1 <- lm(mpg ~ sin(2 * pi * wt), data = mtcars)
```

Is there a way to figure out from `lm1` and `mtcars` that the predictor that is in `lm1` is `wt` (instead of `sin(2 * pi * wt)`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `all.vars` on the formula

```
all.vars(lm1$call[[2]])[3]
[1] "wt"
```

Or with `get_all_vars`

```
names(get_all_vars(lm1$call$formula, mtcars))[3]
[1] "wt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `rsample::form_pred()` (or `all.vars()` directly and subset like the answer above):

```r
lm1 |> terms() |> rsample::form_pred()
```

As `pi` is built-in constant (and one of the only ones in R), a more general solution would remove this:

```r
 terms <- lm1 |> terms() |> all.vars()
 terms[terms != "pi"][-1]
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Constants.html